# Additional readOnlyEntityManager for readOnly from Slave DB

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, replication, persistence-unit

I am exploring ways to achieve reads from slave and writes to master on a JPA based webapp using a MySQL Master/Slave.

I think I have an option to pursue and like some opinions about past experiences achieving the same thing.

To start with , I would like to -

- create an additional persistence Unit called `readOnlyPU`
- create an additional `readOnlyEntityManagerFactory` that uses the `readOnlyPU`
- the `readOnlyPU` and `writeOnlyPU` both share same entity objects meaning 2 different Hibernate Cache with same copy of objects.
- when needed, use the `readOnlyEntityManager`  in my code.

I think this approach should work, but I would like to ask about your opinion about the approach and if such approach is common for enabling Master/Slave replication .